# Guide me with sockets: server-client program that multiplies 2x2-arrays

Tags: c, sockets, client, communication

I'm trying to write a c code with sockets to communicate a server and a client (or parent and child, as you prefer) but I'm really noob at this and I only keep getting errors. I know there are lots of mistakes in my code, but right now I keep getting a "segmentation fault" error. I know that the elements doesn't point each other but it's too late in my country and this all seems like a foreign language to me.
I would really appreciate any help that you could offer me.
That's all, thanks in advance.

SERVER.c CODE-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//#include <sys/un.h>     //per utilitzar sockaddr_un 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 

#include <sys/socket.h>   //per utilitzar sockaddr 
#include <unistd.h> 
#define FEMISSOR "multi.socket"   // per enviar dades a l'emissor  ????????
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  //si es volen utilitzar paràmetres 
int s;          //el socket 
int n;
int i, j; 
char c, num_fill[6]; 
struct sockaddr s_struct; //l'estructura del socket 
unsigned int v;      //per guardar el tamany de s_struct 
char msg[50];       //buffer dels missatges

int a11, a12, a21, a22, b11, b12, b21, b22;
int a, b, x, d; //Las variables que guardan los valores de las matrices.
//Introduccion de los valores de la Matriz 1
printf ("Introduce la primera matriz en orden a11 a12 a21 a22:\n");
scanf ("%d %d %d %d", &a11, &a12, &a21, &a22);
//Introduccion de los valores de la Matriz 2
printf ("Introduce la segunda matriz en orden b11 b12 b21 b22:\n");
scanf ("%d %d %d %d", &b11, &b12, &b21, &b22);
printf ("Los valores de las matrices son: %d %d %d %d; %d %d %d %d\n", a11, a12, a21, a22, b11, b12, b21, b22);
//Realizar la introducción de las matrices


for (i=0;i<4;i++){ 
    printf ("Entra en el for de FORKS\n");
      sprintf(num_fill, "Fill%d", i); 
    if (fork()==0){   //es pot crear un procés fill i executar ./receptor 
        printf ("Entra en el fork %d\n", i);
            execl("./fill", "fill", num_fill, NULL); 
            exit(0);}
    printf ("Imprimeix nom: %s\n", num_fill);
}
printf("Emissor. Esperant uns segons a que el receptor hagi creat el seu socket\n"); 
sleep(1); // ho ha de fer el primer que s'executa per esperar l'altre, de 1s a Xs


if ((s=socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM,0)) <0){  //crea el socket 
  perror ("Emissor. Error socket:"); 
  exit(1); 
}
s_struct.sa_family=AF_UNIX; 
strcpy(s_struct.sa_data, FEMISSOR);          //Emisor
if (bind (s, &s_struct, sizeof(s_struct))<0){  //associa un nom de fitxer al socket 
  perror ("Emissor. Error associant:");      //qui reb és qui ha de fer el bind 
  close(s);       
  exit(2); 
}
for (i=0; i<4; i++){
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        a=a11 ; b=a12 ; x=b11 ; d=b21;
    break;
    case 1:
        a=a11 ; b=a12 ; x=b12 ; d=b22;
    break;
    case 2:
        a=a21 ; b=a22 ; x=b11 ; d=b21;
    break;
    case 3:
        a=a21 ; b=a22 ; x=b12 ; d=b22;
    break;
    }
s_struct.sa_family=AF_UNIX;
sprintf (num_fill, "Fill%d", i); 
strcpy(s_struct.sa_data, num_fill); //envia al fitxer socket del receptor 
v= sizeof(s_struct);
sprintf(msg, "%d %d %d %d", a, b, x, d); 
printf("Multi. Enviant dades a %s", s_struct.sa_data );
if((n=sendto(s, msg, strlen(msg)+1, 0, &s_struct, sizeof(s_struct)))<0) { 
   perror ("Multi. Error enviant:\n"); 
   unlink(num_fill);                   //Al receptor: FRECEPTOR
   close (s); 
   exit(3);     
}     
printf("Emissor. %d dades enviades: %s\n", n, msg); 
}
// for para recibir los datos de los hijos
for (i=0; i<4; i++){

s_struct.sa_family=AF_UNIX;
strcpy(s_struct.sa_data, FEMISSOR); //envia al fitxer socket del receptor
if((n=(recvfrom(s, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, &s_struct, &v)))<0) { 
       perror ("Multi. Error rebent:"); 
       unlink(FEMISSOR);               //Al receptor: FRECEPTOR
       close (s); 
       exit(3);       //Al receptor: n=(recvfrom(s, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, &s_struct, &v))
    }
    if ( strncmp(s_struct.sa_data,"Fill0",5)==0){
        sscanf(msg,"%d", &a);}
    if ( strncmp(s_struct.sa_data,"Fill1",5)==0){
        sscanf(msg,"%d", &b);}
    if ( strncmp(s_struct.sa_data,"Fill2",5)==0){
        sscanf(msg,"%d", &x);}
    if ( strncmp(s_struct.sa_data,"Fill3",5)==0){
        sscanf(msg,"%d", &d);}
    }


printf("Datos recibidos de %s\n", s_struct.sa_data);
printf("Resultado de la multiplicacion:\n");
printf("Matriu 1: %d %d\n %10d %d\n", a11, a12, a21, a22); 
printf("Matriu 2: %d %d\n %10d %d\n", b11, b12, b21, b22);
printf("Matriu R: %d %d\n %10d %d\n\n", a, b, x, d);
printf("Emissor. Prem una tecla per acabar i eliminar el socket\n");

// for para imprimir las matrices.
scanf("%c",&c);
unlink(FEMISSOR);           //es tanca el fitxer que s'ha obert al bind
close(s); 
}
```

---

CLIENT.c CODE

```
//#include <sys/un.h>     //per utilitzar sockaddr_un 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>   //per utilitzar sockaddr 
#include <unistd.h> 
//s'utilitzen dos fitxers, un pel socket de cada procés. Cada procés fa el bind del seu 
//Al sendto y al recvfrom es posa al camp sa_data el fitxer a qui es fa la petició. 
#define FEMISSOR "multi.socket"   // per enviar dades a l'emissor  
#define Fill0 "f0.socket"  // per enviar dades al receptor (si és bidireccional)   <---- i think those lines are not supposed to exist  XD
#define Fill1 "f1.socket"
#define Fill2 "f2.socket"
#define Fill3 "f3.socket"
int main(int argc, char *argv[1]){  //si es volen utilitzar paràmetres 
int s;          //el socket 
int n; 
char c, num_fill[6];
struct sockaddr s_struct; //l'estructura del socket 
unsigned int v;      //per guardar el tamany de s_struct 
char msg[50];       //buffer dels missatges 
int a1, a2, b1, b2;    //Las variables para ingresar los numeros.
int resultado;
strcpy (num_fill, argv[1]);
printf ("Creat %s\n", num_fill);
if ((s=socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM,0))<0){//crea el socket 
perror ("Fill. Error socket:");
exit(1);
}
s_struct.sa_family=AF_UNIX; 
strcpy(s_struct.sa_data, num_fill);          //El receptor utilitzarà el nom FRECEPTOR

i    f (bind (s, &s_struct, sizeof(s_struct))<0){  //associa un nom de fitxer al socket 
  perror ("Fill. Error associant:");      //qui reb és qui ha de fer el bind 
  close(s);       
  exit(2); 
}
s_struct.sa_family=AF_UNIX; 
strcpy(s_struct.sa_data, num_fill);
//Recibe los datos del receptor
if((n=(recvfrom(s, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, &s_struct, &v)))<0) { 
   perror ("Receptor. Error enviant:"); 
   unlink(num_fill);   //Al receptor: FRECEPTOR
   close (s); 
   exit(3);       //Al receptor: n=(recvfrom(s, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0, &s_struct, &v))
} 

printf("Datos recibidos en %s\n", num_fill); 
sscanf(msg,"%d %d %d %d",&a1,&a2,&b1,&b2);
resultado = (a1*b1)+(a2*b2);
printf ("El resultado de %s es: %d\n", num_fill, (int) resultado);
s_struct.sa_family=AF_UNIX;
s    trcpy(s_struct.sa_data, num_fill); //envia al fitxer socket del receptor
v= sizeof(s_struct);
sprintf(msg, "%d", resultado); 
printf("Fill. Enviant resultat a %s\n", s_struct.sa_data );
if((n=sendto(s, msg, strlen(msg)+1, 0, &s_struct, sizeof(s_struct)))<0) { 
   perror ("Emissor. Error enviant:"); 
   unlink(num_fill);               //Al receptor: FRECEPTOR
   close (s); 
   exit(3);     
    }     
printf("%s. %d dades enviades: %s\n", num_fill, n, msg);
unlink(num_fill);           //es tanca el fitxer que s'ha obert al bind    
close(s); 
}
```

---

PS: The code is supposed to be multipliying two 2x2 arrays. The parent creates a socket to communicate with the child. There must be 5 processes: The parent creates 4 child processes that multiply one row for one column to get the 4 resultant integers. Child processes will be parallel-executed.
             Main process creates a socket to communicate with childs that will then be created, codified into an external program. It also passes an arguments that is the # of the child. Childs create their own socket. Each one will use a different file for the linkage (fitxerf1, fitxerf2....fitxerf4). The parent waits 1 second for its child to create the sockets.
             Once the link has been created, the parent passes each child 4 int values using each file. Each child will return to the parent's communication file the solution of each multiplication.
             Eventually, the parent shows what it's receiving from each child and the three arrays (the first ones and the result)

Comment: Can you copy and paste some output? It'll be easier to spot the error if we know how far execution made it..

Comment: the output for the server is:
Introduce la primera matriz en orden a11 a12 a21 a22:
1
4
7 
4
Introduce la primera matriz en orden b11 b12 b21 b22:
5
1
2
5
Los valores de las matrices son: 1 4 7 4; 5 1 2 5
Entra en el for de FORKS
Imprimeix nom: Fill0
Entra en el for de FORKS
Entra en el fork 0
Imprimeix nom: Fill1
Entra en el for de FORKS
Imprimeix nom: Fill2
Entra en el for de FORKS
Imprimeix nom: Fill3
Emissor. Esperant uns segons a que el receptor hagi creat el seu socket
Entra en el fork 3
Entra en el fork 1
Entra en el fork 2
Multi. Error enviant:
: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you help me getting a raw communication pair server-client that creates the 4 processes to send and receive the solved data back? I would be easier for me to understand which commands are used to do it. Thanks a lot again sarnold....can I do anything like voting you into this forum or so?

Comment: Client just keeps saying "segmentation fault", communication is really bad "done".....sigh!

Answer (score 0):

I've avoided editing your post so that it'll be easier for you to add some output; it's nearly impossible to read as it is, and I can't wait to run it through Lindent.

Anyway, I think you should be using `struct sockaddr_un` instead of `struct sockaddr`, so that you can put the pathname into the `sun_path` member. And I think you should clear the entire structure before you use it; either allocate it with `calloc(3)` or use:

```
memset(&s_struct, 0, sizeof(s_struct));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm having a really hard time here. What's the problem? I see the code well formatted

Comment: Do whatever you need to understand this mess. Edit it has you wish, I have lots of saved and non-working versions...The output is already in the code but it's simulated, it's not working to get the 4 resultant row*column int values, but that's the easiest part, when I get this communication thing working, I'll worry about that. The point now is that I keep getting "segmentation fault" at the clients code, I don't know where do I have to point to get it Working. Thanks for your time sarnold, I really appreciate it, sorry for my English, I'm not a native-speaker. Thank you again.